# How can I resolve the exception error for routesetting in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

i'm new to flutter ... i created a page and the i linked it to another, but after routing it, i am getting this error whenever i want to click on the buttons on the next page cause i did'nt have the route specified in all the pages. i can i import for all pages?

```
Another exception was thrown: Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("/transfer", null) in the _WidgetsAppState.
```

this was how i specified in the first page...

```
import 'package:mynewapp/wallet.dart';
import 'package:mynewapp/cards.dart';

void main() => runApp(
      MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(),
        initialRoute: '/',
        routes: {
          '/': (context) => HomePage(),
          '/topup': (context) => TopUp(),
          '/transfer': (context) => Transfer(),
          '/invest': (context) => Invest(),
          '/wallet': (context) => Wallet(),
          '/cards': (context) => Cards(),
        },
      ),
    );
```

After a search through Stackoverflow, This works for me

```
Navigator.push(
                context,
                new MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => new TopUp(),
                ),
              );
```

the problem has been with the calling along, but a new error came up, tho, it works now.....

```
Another exception was thrown: SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'o.remove.bg' (OS Error: No address associated with hostname, errno = 7)
```

i don't understand what this error means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a search through Stackoverflow, This works for me

```
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    new MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => new TopUp(),
                    ),
                  );
```

the problem has been with the calling along.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the following line

```
import 'package:mynewapp/wallet.dart';
import 'package:mynewapp/cards.dart';

void main() => runApp(
      MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(),
        initialRoute: '/',
        routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{//this line
          '/home': (BuildContext context) => HomePage(),
          '/topup': (BuildContext context) => TopUp(),
          '/transfer': (BuildContext context) => Transfer(),
          '/invest': (BuildContext context) => Invest(),
          '/wallet': (BuildContext context) => Wallet(),
          '/cards': (BuildContext context) => Cards(),
        },
      ),
    );
```

Comment: It loads, i'm looking for a way to route with without addin the MaterialApp code above to all pages...

Comment: @MiraBeeCalifonia add MaterialApp i transfer.dart file code

Comment: i just did, same thing

Comment: what is this i dont know ??

Answer (score 0):

```
 routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{

'/home': (context) => HomePage(),
```

Use some route name for your homepage().

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {


static final String routeName = '/home';
```

Define the same name in the HomePage()

Comment: I see, you didn't add home: in the MaterialApp().

Answer (score 0):

**Note: It is not necessary to use a '/' in your routeName.**

In the beginning of every screen, don't forget to assign a static variable like this:

```
  static String routeName = "HomeScreen";
```

The best way to use Named routes is as follows:

1. **Firstly, you need to set an initial route in for your app to start with. you can do that by using the initialRoute attribute of MaterialApp()**

   `runApp(MaterialApp(initialRoute: SplashScreen.routeName,));`
2. **Once that is done, setup routes for all the screens present in your app by using routes attribute of MaterialApp().**

```
runApp(MaterialApp(  
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,  
    initialRoute: SplashScreen.routeName,  
    routes: {  
      SplashScreen.routeName: (context) => SplashScreen(),  
      HomeScreen.routeName: (context) => HomeScreen(),  
      LoginScreen.routeName: (context) => LoginScreen(),  
}));
```

3. **Now, your task for setting up Routes is done. All you need to do is write the Navigation code correctly in all the screens.**

   For example, in the code that I have shared above, if I want to navigate from SplashScreen to HomeScreen, I will write the code as:

   > Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, HomeScreen.routeName);

   (or)

   > Navigator.pushNamed(context, HomeScreen.routeName);

This procedure is a generalized approach which can be used to overcome almost all routing problems.